# специфика язык, почему текст "===========" не выводится между выводами массива numbers

Tags: golang

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")

    var numbers [3]int = [3]int{}
    for index, value := range numbers {
        fmt.Println(index, value)
    }

    println("==========")

    p := "Tolya"
    if p == "Tolya" {
        for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
            fmt.Println(numbers[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вообще говоря, выводится https://go.dev/play/p/VO7Ylxjt0i8

Answer (score 1):

Потому что нужно писать имя пакета, чью функцию вы используете.

```
fmt.Println("==========")
```

Comment: Самое забавное заключается в том, что в самом коде УЖЕ есть `fmt.Println("Hello")` :)

Comment: Использование `fmt.Println` не запрещает использование `println`, поэтому твой ответ не является объяснением проблемы. Правда не факт, что проблема вообще есть. В минимальном примере не воспроизводится https://go.dev/play/p/VO7Ylxjt0i8